# QUERY with IMPORTRANGE returns "Unable to parse query string ..."

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

We are currently trying to set up the following formula:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1uyazplHdGpZeBZWOv3TbnIUfWeHQGyZF5mRsNuWxkO4","Data Salesforce!A:Z"),"Select A Where J = 'Spain'",-1)
```

The idea is to look for a QUERY with data coming from an IMPORTRANGE.

We get the following error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   NO_COLUMNA

Any idea how we could resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of identifying the columns by Alphabetical index you need to reference them by numerical index.

I assume this is because `importrange()` doesn't really import the range but just the values.
Try

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1uyazplHdGpZeBZWOv3TbnIUfWeHQGyZF5mRsNuWxkO4","Data Salesforce!A:Z"),"Select Col1 Where Col8 = 'Spain'",-1)
```